# How to run --coverage-html unittest in magento 2 and where to see generated report report

Tags: magento2

When I run below command its run but where is report?

```
phpunit -c dev/tests/unit/phpunit.xml --coverage-html ./report vendor/magento/module-contact/Test/Unit
```

Where to see report in `html` format.

Answer (score 1):

Generated report will store at this path:

> Magento root > coverage